# jQuery UI Drag and Drop - expand height of drop area on hover

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I am trying to expand the height of a drop area using jQuery UI's drag and drop functionality and it doesn't seem to be working as I would expect.  Please see the following fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/pn226rj9/

Note that I am expanding the height from 10px to 120px on hover:

```
.ui-state-hover {
    height:120px !important;
}
```

What I would expect to happen is that when the drop area height grows, that becomes the 'new' height of the drop area and I can now hover over that entire area while still being in a hover state.

However, it looks like jQuery is remembering the original height of the drop area and treating that as the de facto height regardless of what I change it to.  This results in the hover state going away while appearing to still be in the drop area.

Is there anyway to make jQuery recognize this new height?

Comment: your ui-state-hover class gets added to the element on the hover action only and then gets removed from the element when you are no longer hovering on the element which restores the elements height.

Comment: Right, but the ui-state-hover class is added while I'm hovering over the element, so while I'm hovering the height of that element should now be 120px.  Therefore I should be able to move anywhere within that 120px and still be in a hover state.  It works with CSS:  http://jsfiddle.net/1w78hmg3/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `refreshPositions` attribute to `true`...

```
$("#draggable").draggable({ refreshPositions: true});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pn226rj9/3/

Comment: Incredible, that is exactly what I needed.  Thank you so much.